# How could I get different sections/boxes/images of my site to load at the *same* time?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, image

I have a site that is divided into 3 key sections, Box A, B and C.

Box A contains a large image. Box B contains 6 thumbnails of smaller images. Box C contains a medium-sized image.

If the user clicks on the image in Box A, another image is loaded into Box A, while simultaneously, Box B is reloaded with 6 new random thumbnails, and Box C now contains a smaller version of the previous image in Box A.

Currently, images in these boxes load at different times/speeds, making the UX look awkward (that is, Box C might load before B, and B before A). How could I ensure that all the images load at **exactly the same time** (essentially, ensure that all images load at the same time that the last image is loaded)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JavaScript preloading](http://elouai.com/javascript-preload-images.php) to cache every image when the document is loaded. As long as nobody clicks on your images too quickly, you'll have the desired results.

Another option is to combine all the images into a single large graphic and use CSS to show only the part you want. However, this is really only practical when several small images are involved.

Comment: Would preloading work with random images (new images are loaded whenever the site is refreshed)?

Comment: Sure, you just have to preload every single possible image that might be randomly selected.

Comment: Ah, but that would not work in my favor, considering there are likely to be several thousands of images.